# How does the current go back up in a high frequency current loop?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc

In an SMPS, it is said to reduce the size of the high frequency current loop as it is shown in orange on the below schematic :

[image]

I understand that it will reduce the parasitic inductance if the loop area is reduced and so on the EMI if we accept that the current can loop.  I do not understand how the current can go back up through the bypass capacitor.

[image]

If the DC voltage across the capacitor is 1000 V, does it mean that locally the AC voltage at the PGND pin of the capacitor has to rise above 1000 V due to the parasitic inductance? Is it really possible? If it is, what happens if the DC voltage is 10 kV? What if the parasitic inductor is lower, if the loop area is really small, and the current is low?

Comment: Apply the AC equivalent principle: (large) capacitors become short circuits, DC sources are shorted out, (large) inductors are open circuit. Current flows through the capacitors because the voltage is changing (I = C dV/dt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitor is the local power supply for high frequency currents. And current needs a loop to flow, so let's look at the path it takes.

For CBST:

If you just consider it as battery, current from capacitor goes into driver supply pin, comes out of driver output pin, goes from FET gate to source and since current needs a loop to flow, it flows into capacitor.

For CIN:

When high side FET turns on, current from capacitor flows via high side FET and inductor to output load and capacitor, and again since current must flows in a loop, the return path of current flows back to capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

This is the so called "hot" loop of the switching converter, the loop with the highest dI/dt. You find it by considering the current flow during "on" (red) and "off" (blue) periods and subtracting them (green) ([Source](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/layout-for-power-designs-1-hot-loops.html)):

[image]

In a synchronous buck, it is between the half-bridge and the input capacitance.

It is a loop for AC current, so the capacitor presents no problem for this to work.

The current for its recharging during the "off" period is sourced from the rail power supply. The voltage across the input capacitor stays nearly constant the whole time.